# How can I resolve CSS conflict between ExtJS 3 and Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, extjs3

Our application developed with ExtJS 3. Now we started refactoring with usage of Twitter Bootstrap. Unfortunately these two nice libraries are not able to live together because of conflicts of names in styles.
As I know there several solutions to fix this problem in ExtJS 4. But what about old 3th version ?

Comment: were you able to find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you will ever see a solution coming from Sencha about this as support for v3 will soon be dropped (v5 just came out). Also, bootstrap and extjs don't just conflict with style names but also both want to direct the page layout. As you have maybe found out, Ext 4+ includes an `ext-all-scoped.css` that can be used to prevent overlapping names. (and even then there's some work to do).

So either you have to manually handle each conflict yourself, or you have to upgrade your Ext version. (going from ext 3 to ext 4 is a heavy load of work unfortunately...)